Setting Up OpenVPN on Ubuntu Server for 10,000 Clients: Guidance Needed
I have an Ubuntu server where I need to set up OpenVPN to connect 10,000 other Ubuntu clients. I’m encountering difficulties with the setup. Could you please share any simple, effective references or guidance on how to achieve this? Thank you!

The OpenVPN website has complete "simple, effective references or guidance"
